# Duplicate bin/ directories from Apache Spark install with Homebrew

Tags: apache-spark, homebrew

When installing Apache Spark 2.2.1 through Homebrew, the resulting install location seems to have two slightly-different `bin/` directories, one a level below the other.  (Directory structure at the bottom of this question.)

My main concern is that the `load-spark-env.sh` (Spark environment variable load script) looks pretty drastically different between the two, and it's tough to confirm which is being used.

In short, I'm wondering:

- Why might there be two similar `bin/` directories here?  Sorry if I'm missing something obvious about Spark setup.
- If I have `$SPARK_HOME` set to `libexec/` (see below), will the `bin/` here always be referenced over the other directory, or are there other environment variables that I need to set?

#### Info

I have the following set in `~/.bash_profile`:

```
export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home"
export SPARK_HOME="/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.2.1/libexec"
export PYSPARK_PYTHON="/Users/brad/anaconda3/bin/python3"
```

Homebrew's install file is [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/apache-spark.rb), for reference.

The directory looks like this (I've excluded some irrelevant folders such as sbin):

```
Cellar$ tree -l apache-spark/
apache-spark/
└── 2.2.1
    ├── INSTALL_RECEIPT.json
    ├── LICENSE
    ├── NOTICE
    ├── README.md
    ├── bin
    │   ├── find-spark-home
    │   ├── load-spark-env.sh
    │   ├── pyspark
    │   ├── run-example
    │   ├── spark-beeline
    │   ├── spark-class
    │   ├── spark-shell
    │   ├── spark-sql
    │   ├── spark-submit
    │   └── sparkR
    └── libexec
        ├── bin
        │   ├── find-spark-home
        │   ├── load-spark-env.sh
        │   ├── pyspark
        │   ├── run-example
        │   ├── spark-beeline
        │   ├── spark-class
        │   ├── spark-shell
        │   ├── spark-sql
        │   ├── spark-submit
        │   └── sparkR
        ├── conf
        ├── ...
        └── yarn
```

**Edit**: I've noticed this same structure with brew-installed Hadoop, so it looks like the question pertains more to Homebrew than the tools it installs.

Answer (score 0):

> Why might there be two similar bin/ directories here? Sorry if I'm missing something obvious about Spark setup.

The higher level bin directory contains just some wrappers that override the JAVA_HOME variable and start the executables in the libexec directory. These wrappers are then placed in your /usr/local/bin directory so that you can use things like spark-shell without specifying the full path.

> If I have $SPARK_HOME set to libexec/ (see below), will the bin/ here always be referenced over the other directory, or are there other environment variables that I need to set?

If you do need to set the SPARK_HOME directory for whatever reason, then you're right to set it to the libexec one and not the higher level bin directory.

Comment: Thanks—not that I distrust the answer, but is there any sort of documentation that refers to this?